# Managing Reports in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a scenario where I have to show a huge report which consists of about 16 fields, and the last field consists of a radio group. I've taken a Table layout for this. But the problem is, I don't know the size of each field. I mean, there could be 50 characters in one, and 2 in another, and I have to adjust the width and height basing on that without loosing the look and feel criteria. For example,the first column is a Serial No which may contain 4 digits max, the second column contains an ID which may be a 20 digit number and so on. I can use Wrap Content, but its making the page clumsy! So, my question is, is there any possibility that my fields can automatically set their width and height basing on the length of the characters.Thanks in advance! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is `android:maxLength="X"` what your looking for?